# Error if don't check if {{object.field}} exists

Tags: variables, properties, null, angular

I have a question about checking if some field in object exists.

I want to print all categories which user has so I'm doing something like this:

```
  <ul *ngIf="user.categories.length >  0" *ngFor="#category of user.categories">
    <li>
      {{category.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The reason? All the data are **PROPERLY** printed, but I'm getting an error in web console like this:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

But when I do something like:

```
  <ul *ngIf="user.categories.length >  0" *ngFor="#category of user.categories">
    <li *ngIf="category">
      {{category.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then all is okay.

Am I doing something wrong or maybe I have to check this every time? Have you ever had a problem like this one?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

**basic usage**

Use the safe-navigation operator

```ts
{{category?.name}}
```

then `name` is only read when `category` is not `null`.

**array**

This only works for the `.` (dereference) operator. 
For an array you can use

```ts
{{records && records[0]}}
```

See also [Angular 2 - Cannot read property '0' of undefined error with context ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423276/angular-2-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-error-with-context-error-conte/38423299#38423299)

**async pipe**

With `async` pipe it can be used like

```ts
{{(chapters | async)?.length
```

**`ngModel`**

With `ngModel` currently it needs to be split into

```ts
[ngModel]="details?.firstname" (ngModelChange)="details.firstname = $event"
```

See also [Data is not appending to template in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080980/data-is-not-appending-to-template-in-angular2/39081182#39081182)

**`*ngIf`**

An alternative is always to wrap the part of the view with `*ngIf="data"` to prevent the part being rendered at all before the `data` is available to prevent the dereference error.

Comment: Yup, doesn't work for `ngModel` bindings. Still missing the Angular1's auto generated properties which were extremely handy for client-server CRUD operations.

Comment: @Hani I don't know Angular1. Can you point me to some information about auto generated properties?

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-model="category.name" />` and the name being null  would auto generate the name property as soon as user types in the textbox. Not to mention that elvis operator doesn't work for `[(ngModel)]`. Would be nice to have it there too.

Comment: They discussed recently to make elvis operator behavior the default. Likely they'll make some improvment. Probably not too soon.

Comment: I get why `category?.name` is a suitable replacement for doing `*ngIf="category"`, but why do you have to check for it to exist at all?  It exists or `*ngIf` would not be true and we wouldn't get a list printed.  I'm experiencing this as well so I'm not questioning the solution - it works - I just don't understand why it is required.  What is occurring that means there is a null category at some point?

Comment: Exactly, in this example `?.`  is only relevant for `null` categories.

Comment: OK - well take for example section 5.18 of this tutorial: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views

In that last template section if I omit the `*ngIf` I get the `Cannot read property` error, but it is fine if I add it.  There is only one `party`, not a list where one might be `null` (at least from what I can see).  This may be some oddity that I'm not used to from Meteor but it doesn't make a lot of sense on the surface.

Comment: This is usually when `party` is acquired asynchronically. When Angular renders the view the first time, `party` is still `null` and `party.name` throws. With `*ngIf="party"` only when `party` becomes `!= null`, then this part of the view is added to the DOM and the bindings are resolved and there is no error because this part only is evaluated after Angular ensured `part != null`.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense.  Seems kind of inefficient that with even such a simple page it renders more than once, but I guess I'll have to learn a bit more before I worry about that.

Comment: The page doesn't render again. Just the part that was excluded previously by `*ngIf` gets added when the expression becomes true.

Comment: I was looking for this answer but is hard to find angular2-4 answers. Thank you is so simple and works well!

Comment: if the value has another level like category-->name-->rating then simply do this {{category?.name?.rating}}