# Angular 2 - Cannot read property '0' of undefined error with context ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]

Tags: typescript, angular

my service is like this

```
getRecords(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.fetchAdminData)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

and Extract data is as following

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
```

In my component i am calling this as follows

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {FormsHandler} from '../services/service.forms'


@Component({
  selector: 'form-admin',
  templateUrl: '../partials/form5.html'
})

export class FormAdminComponent implements OnInit {
  public records
  constructor(private formHandler : FormsHandler){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.formHandler.getRecords().subscribe(res => {
      if (res.ok){
        this.records = res.data
        console.log(res)
        console.log(this.records[0])
      }
    })
  }

}
```

But when this is called on as follows in html it errors

```
{{records}} // this is working perfectly 
    {{records[0]}}  //Cannot read property '0' of undefined ERROR CONTEXT:    [object Object]
```

also i even cannot access my nested object like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">
              <td>{{record.firstName + " "+ record.middleName+ " "+ record.LastName}}</td>
              <td>{{record.BankingDetails.company}} </td> // This results in errorTypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined
              <td>{{record.BankingDetails}} </td> //working fine but resulting in [object Object]

              <td>Pending</td>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined

my response is like this

```
Object {ok: true, data: Array[2]}
```

and complete data is like this :

```
[
 {
"Address": {
"addressLine1":  "nh" ,
"addressLine2":  "nghn" ,
"city":  "ngh" ,
"formStatus": 2 ,
"pinCode":  "ngh" ,
"state":  "nghn"
} ,
"BankingDetails": {
"bankName":  "csdcss" ,
"company":  "cd" ,
"designation":  "kn" ,
"loanAmount":  "csd" ,
"loanPurpose":  "cs" ,
"panCardNumber":  "84894848" ,
"salary":  "55"
} ,
"contact":  "vsd" ,
"date":  "vsd" ,
"dob": Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
"email": abhishek@gmail.com, »
"firstName":  "cs" ,
"firstname":  "" ,
"formStatus": 3 ,
"gender":  "male" ,
"id":  "98fd72b9-62fe-4fcd-90d6-f2a5f83c052b" ,
"isAdmin": 1 ,
"lastName":  "vs" ,
"lastname":  "" ,
"middleName":  "vds" ,
"middlename":  "" ,
"month":  "vsd" ,
"password": <binary, 60 bytes, "24 32 61 24 31 30..."> ,
"username":  "" ,
"year":  "vs"
},
...
]
```

i did't getting what am i doing wrong becuase its working fine with console.log and printing a json but is not accessible with html

also i noted that when i am using

```
{{records}}
```

its resulting in [object Object]

i have to explicitly write

```
{{records | json}}
```

to get my complete data

Hey please suggest me what i am doing wrong i want to access my nested elements like records.BankingDetails.company

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got a solution to this problem as per @Akshay Rao suggestions
i used these so that data is available before rendering of page

```
<div *ngIf="records">
</div>
```

also as per @Günter Zöchbauer suggestion i do require to use (Elvis) operator like

```
{{record.BankingDetails?.company}}
```

and it worked well .
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You are fetching `records` async and when Angular tries to resolve bindings the first time `records` is still `null` therefore `records[0]` fails.

You can instead use

```ts
{{records && records[0]}}
```

For other expressions you can use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator like

```ts
{{records?.someprop}}
```

but there is no safe-navigation for array index access (`?[]`)

Comment: this is not working
 {{records || records[0]}}
please suggest me how to access nested element like record.BankingDetail.company

Comment: I fixed it. Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: i used this {{records && records[0]}} 
but resulting in [object Object] instead of my json data

Comment: I can't know what `records` or `records[0]`returns. Your question doesn't provide any info. You can try `{{records && (records[0] | json)}}`

Comment: {{records && (records[0] | json)}} yeah this is resulting in json data but want to ask how to access nested element because without using pipe its resulting in error

Comment: Just add the property name you want to show at that place `{{records && records[0].someProp}}`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you need to use this sintax (record && record[0].property) every time an object is fetched asynchronously? this could lead to very verbose html components?

Comment: No, this is to avoid errors when `records` is `null` or `undefined`. This can also happen if you don't fetch it async. This is required because **there is no** `records?[0]`

Answer (score 3):

records initially is null and gets the value once the repsonse from the server comes

You should use

```
{{ records }}

{{records && records[0]}}
```

Comment: hey piyush explain me how to access my nested element like
record.BankingDetails.company

because{{records && records[0]}} is resulting in [object, Object]

Answer (score 1):

1. if u are getting [object object] then u will have to first stringify the content and then parse that content like below...

> var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(records));

2. If u are accessing your nested elements then you have 2 options for that too ...
   2(a). either u can declare them as empty array or objects which is not a good idea but still it will help u ...

> ```
> on initialization :-
> records.bankingDetails = {};
> ```

2(b).The one which is approved by angular team is that u have to use a ngIf on top of your div where u are using the nested elements ..

this is all what u need :)

Comment: Thanks Akshay step 2(b) worked and i do get records[0] BUT strangely
this also results in [object Object]
i even used var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(records)); but still i didnt get json there by resulting in error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined
when i use this 
{{record.BankingDetails.company}}
but i do getting its value

Comment: u mean u get this in ur console when u  make a getrecords call ??

Comment: yeah i used elvis operator and now its woring

Comment: but i really need to know unlike angularjs why all these elvis things needs to be there in angular2

Comment: if u just want to see the data then u can just stringify it with JSON.stringify(records) in ur console... but if u want to access the values u need to parse them in objects ... no need of elvis bro ...i just tried stringify which gave me ur result which was before [object object]

Comment: i hope u got the answer for your question ... enjoy coding :)