# Angular 2 - get datas from a json file

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular2-template

How can I get my datas from a JSON in an angular 2 project? I tried (code below) but this doesn't work. Maybe I forgot some details... thanks a lot for an answer

Ps. I need to display on my html that "uno" included in json file.

app.component.ts:

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import {Http} from '@angular/http';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-header',
        templateUrl: '../partials/app.header.html',
        styleUrls: ['../css/partials/app.header.css']
    })
        export class AppComponent {
          title = 'app works!';
          data;
          constructor(private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('app/header.json')
               .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
          }
        }
```

app.module.ts:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

app.header.html:

```
<header>
    {{title}}//this works
    {{elemento}}//here i want to show "uno" included in json file
    ...
</header>
```

header.json:

```
    {
        "elemento": "uno" 
    }
```

Comment: you should give preference to the answer posted first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
{{data?.elemento}}
```

Comment: in my opinion there is no reason

Comment: @Jamil89 put a elvis operator and try  updated answer

Comment: THANKS! Now it works...i needed to write "?" next to data. How i can find documentation about this particular  to improve my knowledge? thanks

Comment: until the `get` request is successful, `this.data` is undefined. So when you try to access `data.elemento`, the error occurs. More on `safe-navigation operator` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911295/3082296

Comment: just to add on it by @adiga any http call is an async call so it takes some time by the time the template is rendered the data is not yet back from http call.so we use the  elvis operator for the same

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
<header>
    {{title}}
    {{data?.elemento}}
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

get method should be returned so use RX js observable pattern
just like this :http://davidpine.net/blog/angular-2-http/

```js
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import {Http} from '@angular/http';
     import * from rxjs;

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-header',
        templateUrl: '../partials/app.header.html',
        styleUrls: ['../css/partials/app.header.css'],
        providers:[]
    })
       
  export class AppComponent {
          title = 'app works!';
          data :any;
          constructor(private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('app/header.json')
               .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json())
                .map((res: Response) => <observable[]>response.json())            
                            .catch(this.handleError);
          }
        }
```

```html
<header>
    {{title}}
    {{data?.elemento}}
</header>
```