# angular 4 cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular

i'm trying to use angular 4 to call to a dummy web api, here is my component

```js
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    url = 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json';
    results: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.results = data.json();
        })
    }

    getData() {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }

}
```

but when i try to display it i get the result but also a screen of error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
```

what i want to understand is why it is shown because after a split second the data is well displayed .

Comment: Add *ngIf="results" in the template

Comment: try results?.ip this will work

Comment: you can put the template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - error if don't check if {{object.field}} exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910928/angular2-error-if-dont-check-if-object-field-exists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `*ngFor` you can change it to `*ngFor="let r of results | async"`

Your problem is that the data isn't there yet, so it can't read the id property.

If you use the async pipe, it should wait for the data to come before displaying it.

Answer (score 8):

Make use of Elvis Operator instead i:e safe operator

```
{{results?.ip}}
```

Comment: thank you but i can't do that in all my project i was wondering if im doing something out of the standards

Answer (score 5):

You get this error also if you add your component to the import array instead of the declaration array.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    someComponent
  ],

  declarations: [...],
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Should be

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
  ],

  declarations: [...,someComponent],
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

put {{results}} in your html part. You'll see the value the server give you.

Maybe you should use *ngfor when you get the values and use an async pipe on it to display it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


this.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.results = data;
 });
}

getData() {
     return this.http.get(this.url).map(resp => resp.json());
}
```

and add this in the template

```
*ngIf="results"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


this.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.results = data;
 });
}

getData() {
     return this.http.get(this.url).map(resp => resp.json());
}
```

HTML part

```
*ngFor="let r of results | async"
 <p>{{r}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one property you can use a class and inject them there , then it would be no problem .
otherwise if you have just one single variable and u want it to be displayed pls use the ***safe navigation operator*** `user?.name`