# Angular RxJs Observable works as string but not as interface or class

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

My view does not get updated from Observable<class> but gets updated from Observable<string>.

> ts file: *status.component.ts*

```
stat$: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.stat$ = new Observable(o => o.next('This is status text');
  }
```

> template file: *status.component.html*

```
<span class="status">{{ stat$ | async }}</span>
```

I get the desired result in browser showing:

***This is status text***

So far so good, HOWEVER:

Here is my (newbie) problem when trying to use an interface or class instead of plain string - such as this:

> ts file: *status.model.ts*

```
export interface StatusStruct {
    id?: number;
    counter?: number;
    timestamp?: string;
    isCompleted?: boolean;
    isError?: boolean;
    statusText?: string;
}
```

> file: status.component.ts

```
import { StatusStruct } from './status.model';

stSt: StatusStruct;
stat$: Observable<StatusStruct>;

  constructor() {

    this.stSt = {
      id: 1,
      counter: 1,
      isCompleted: false,
      statusText: 'This is status text'
    };

    this.stat$ = new Observable(o => o.next(this.stSt);
  }
```

> and in my template file: *status.component.html*

```
<span class="status">{{ stat$.statusText | async }}</span>
```

Would you please explain why the 'this.stat$' is not updated by: 'this.stSt' and does not show in view/browser? It compiles fine and the browser debugger shows no exceptions. Thank you.

Comment: try `{{ (stat$ | async).statusText }}`

Comment: Yes, sir, works - and much appreciated.

Comment: Also you may try `{{ (stat$ | async | json )}}`

Comment: Not sure if you adding a `?` in there would be helpful too. Could someone confirm? `{{ (stat$ | async)?.statusText }}` - per this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910928/error-if-dont-check-if-object-field-exists Only I seem to recall having page loading issues with something like that in the past.